Angular 19: NullInjector errors in production build even when project is stripped to bare minimum
I have 2 projects written in Ionic with Angular 19 which are giving Nullinjector errors in production environment and not in development builds. In order to find out what would be causing these, I stripped one of my projects down to the bare minimum and I am still getting these Nullinjector errors. I'm not able to get more information about e.g. incorrect providers because the Nullinjector errors do not give more details in production. Example of the error:
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError[t -> _i -> _i]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for _i!

The minimal app.config.ts looks like this:
import { ApplicationConfig, importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { provideRouter, withPreloading, PreloadAllModules } from '@angular/router';
import { routes } from './app-routing.module';
import { provideAuth, getAuth, indexedDBLocalPersistence, browserLocalPersistence } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { isPlatform } from '@ionic/angular';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    provideAuth(() => {
      const auth = getAuth();
      if (isPlatform('android')) {
        auth.setPersistence(indexedDBLocalPersistence);
      } else {
        auth.setPersistence(browserLocalPersistence);
      }
      return auth;
    }),
    provideRouter(routes, withPreloading(PreloadAllModules)),
    importProvidersFrom(IonicModule.forRoot())
  ]
};

What could be missing here?

I think you will be missing an import somewhere - have you tried ng serve --prod --optimization=false

@JamesP Yes, I have tried that. Without optimization (or as development build) everything works as expected.

Doesn't seem to be happening for me on a fresh project with neither @angular/fire@19.0.0-rc4 nor @angular/fire@18.0.1. You might try to find out what _i refers to in your build by inspecting the code at the stack trace points. Perhaps you'll be able to look the real name of the class up based on the code you see. Once you know the real name, it must be easier to solve the error.

@NorthFred, did you manage to get this working? There is not much I can suggest other than trying to debug the minified .js.

@JamesP I enabled source maps but even that got me stuck. I'm not able to get more info out of the minified js...

Instead of using @angular/fire, you can directly use the core Firebase SDK to initialize and work with Firebase services. Here's how you can do it:
1. Install Firebase Core SDK
Run the following command to install the Firebase Core SDK:
npm i firebase

2. Firebase Service (firebase.service.ts)
First, set up a Firebase service to handle initialization:
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FirebaseApp, initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { Auth, getAuth, initializeAuth, indexedDBLocalPersistence } from 'firebase/auth';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class FirebaseService {
  firebaseAuth!: Auth;
  constructor(private readonly platform: Platform) {}

  private firebaseAuthInitialization(app: FirebaseApp): Auth {
    if (this.platform.is('capacitor')) {
      // use IndexedDB persistence for native platforms
      return initializeAuth(app, { persistence: indexedDBLocalPersistence });
    } else {
      // use default persistence for web platforms
      return getAuth(app);
    }
  }

  public async initializeApp(): Promise<void> {
    const app = initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig);
    this.firebaseAuth = this.firebaseAuthInitialization(app);
  }
}

3. App Component (app.component.ts)
Then, Call the firebase service in app component file.
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FirebaseService } from './services/firebase.service';

@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private readonly firebaseService: FirebaseService) {
    this.firebaseService.initializeApp();
  }
}



I tried as you suggested, but I run into this error: ERROR Error: invalid     invalidFactory Angular     AuthService_Factory main.js:1921     Angular 7     AppComponent_Factory app.component.ts:26     Angular 15

Could you also upload a screenshot showing how you set it up and how you are calling the methods?

Alternatively, you can upload a simple project on GitHub with the basic setup, and I will take a look at it.

Please check here: https://github.com/NorthFred/temporary.git

Hey, I have run your project and tried to log in with both email/password and Google login, and it's working properly on both Android and web.

Did you run it in production mode? ionic serve --configuration production gives the error.

Still not getting any error.

My bad :/ I uploaded the wrong branch. Please check from here: https://github.com/NorthFred/temp.git

It doesn't look like the issue is with Firebase integration. It seems you're trying to convert an Angular 18 NgModule project to an Angular 19 standalone application, and the version upgrade process wasn't done completely correctly, which is why you're facing this issue.

That is indeed the case. Any ideas as what could be the main reason?

Please update the Angular version to 19 without changing it to standalone. You can keep the existing NgModule as it is.

I tried that by declaring standalone = false in all components. This still results in a nullinjector error in the production build, although a different one: Uncaught NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Platform: core)[t -> Us]:    NullInjectorError: No provider for Us  This error only occurs in Angular 19.

You can simply go to your previous Angular 18 project and run the ng update command. Additionally, you can refer to the official update guide here: https://angular.dev/update-guide

There's an issue on the Ionic github pages, others are running into the same errors: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/30100
